# View PDF on iPad from Windows 7 over WiFi

Tags: data-synchronization, pdf, applications

I have a home fileserver running Windows 7. I have a directory with PDF files. I want to view the PDF files on my iPad 2 over WiFi and not locally store them on the iPad. Is there any app which can help me? I tried to read the [Goodreader docs](http://www.goodiware.com/gr-man-tr-servers.html#sync) and could not find much information without buying it on the iPad. Can someone help?

Comment: GoodReader will copy/sync the pdfs to your iPad for reading. If you can run a web server on your Windows box, you might just be able to use Safari.

Comment: Does that fileserver expose any shares through particular services? Do you have access to the file server to make adjustments? As in, could you start a web server or a different share on that machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a web-server on it.
[Look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software#Overview) and choose one you would like or even [here for smaller ones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers)

Then put PDF in web server directory or designate current one in webserver configuration.

After that you'll be able to use just Safari to read that PDFs